# Which java is used in a maven project if the pom file and the .gitlab-ci.yml file can reference different versions

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

I have a maven application where in the pom file it looks like its specifying java 8 as the compiler:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
```

But we host the code in Gitlab and subsequently push our applications to the target vm through Gitlab's CI/CD pipeline.  So this apps `.gitlab-ci.yml` file we do have a `compile` job before we push the application's jar file to the target vm and the `compile` job can specify a different java version:

```
compile:
  image: openjdk:11-jdk
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean package
  artifacts:
    paths:
```

My question is which version of java would actually be run when I push this application to Gitlab's ci/cd pipeline, will it be jdk8 as specified in the pom.xml or openjdk11 as specified in the yml's compile job?

Comment: The pom doesn't specify the version of the compiler being ran.

Comment: The `<source>` and `<target>` elements correspond to the `--source` and `--target`  command line arguments of [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/javac.html) (also see `--release`). They do not mandate the version of the _compiler_.

Comment: Also you are using very old plugin version...

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the comments already given:

When you run Maven (be it on the command line directly or via Jenkins, Travis, Github Action, etc) some Java version must be used. After all Maven is a Java based application. The Java environment of choice is the one referred to by the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

So if your .gitlab-ci.yml mandates OpenJDK 11 to be used, that is the compiler of choice. However due to the settings within the pom this JDK11 compiler is instructed to only allow Java 8 language elements (source=1.8) and to produce bytecode compatible with the Java 8 runtime environment (target=1.8).

From https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/man/javac.html:

***--source release** or **-source release**
Compiles source code according to the rules of the Java programming language for the specified Java SE release. The supported values of release are the current Java SE release and a limited number of previous releases, detailed in the command-line help.
If the option is not specified, the default is to compile source code according to the rules of the Java programming language for the current Java SE release.*

***--target release** or **-target release**
Generates class files suitable for the specified Java SE release. The supported values of release are the current Java SE release and a limited number of previous releases, detailed in the command-line help.
Note: The target release must be equal to or higher than the source release. (See --source.)*